# What's the easiest way to use vertical and horizontal splitting in Visual Studio at the same time?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2012, editor

As seen on the screenshot below, marked by red arrows:

[image: Screenshot]

If I use `Vertical Tab Split` subwindow, I lose the ability to split insert another tab and split it horizontally. Is there any addon or setting I can change to be able to put my code tabs in sort of rectangle-grid?

Just to clarify - I don't want to see the same file contents twice. I want every tab to show a different file. I can't find the reason why such an oversimplification to ide was introduced.

I know it can be solved by opening many standalone windows, but that's hardly an answer for me.

[Here's the example of how it looks like in Sublime 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkAdE.png)

Comment: Yeah, I see your issue. Multiple instances seems to be the only solution for VS.

Comment: omg wtf is that?! All-caps menu bar? And everything's black! And those tiny scrollbars!!!!!?!??!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: @jesse: that's disgraceful

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit this is kind of off topic already, but the theme colors are changeable (out of the box you get light gray and the *pictured* dark gray). Here's a read if you'd like, [A DESIGN WITH ALL-CAPS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/06/05/a-design-with-all-caps.aspx) and [Visual Studio 11 User Interface Updates Coming in RC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/05/08/visual-studio-11-user-interface-updates-coming-in-rc.aspx).

Comment: Split screens are paneful.

Answer (score 8):

As you have discovered it's not a feature of the VS shell. For reference, it wasn't possible in VS2010 either.

You can vote for this feature on the Visual Studio Developer Community site - there's [a specific request for it here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/351247/split-visual-studio-windows-horizontally-and-verti.html)

Comment: Is that site connected to MS in any way? I am also looking for some addon or something that could do it; it can take years before vanilla VS changes that.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft monitors the site closely and uses the suggestions to guide and refine their development efforts. Not every suggestion will make it into the product (obviously) but everything gets at least some consideration.

Comment: Dead link; site has been removed.

Comment: @timelmer it was migrated to the Dev Community site when they closed down the User Voice forums. I've updated the answer. Thanks for letting me know.